# Did Julius Caesar ban low-birth people wearing pearls?

Tags: roman-empire, julius-caesar

I encountered this

> "in I century B.C., during the Julius Caesar consulship, it was promulgated a law that prohibited the theirs *[sic]* use by the lower classes" *[RomeAndArt](http://romeandart.eu/en/art-pearls-empresses.html)*

statement several times, but the source remains unclear. Could anyone help finding the source or debunking the myth, please?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a specific [sumptuary law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sumptuary_law); I can't find any record of a Roman sumptuary law governing pearls, but I only took a quick skim.

Comment: _always_ update the question, not the comment.

Comment: seems kind of redundant to me,  pearls were literally so expensive i doubt anyone who wasnt rich could even dream of owning them (aside from the rare cases of war trophies after a campaign)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gaius Suetonius Tranquillus, "De Vitis Caesarum", 43:

> Lecticarum usum, item conchyliatae vestis et **margaritarum** nisi certis personis et aetatibus perque certos dies ademit.

In classical Russian translation by Gasparov it's "pearls":

> Носил­ки, а так­же пур­пур­ные пла­тья и **жем­чуж­ные укра­ше­ния** он оста­вил в употреб­ле­нии толь­ко для опре­де­лен­ных лиц, опре­де­лен­ных воз­рас­тов и в опре­де­лен­ные дни.

I'm not sure what English translation is relevant. The only one I can find for some reason talks about "jewels" instead of "pearls":

> The use of litters for travelling, purple robs, and **jewels**, he permitted only to persons of a certain age and station, and on particular days.

Comment: This is a quite good English translation: https://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Roman/Texts/Suetonius/12Caesars/home.html. "Margarita" means "pearl". Jewel was in the Classic Latin of Suetonius "gemma", "lapillus" or (poetically) "lapis" (in Post-Classic Latin, like in the Digest, sometimes margarita was also used).